# HTML Drop-Down Menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop-down menu for a webpage, but I don't like how it looks. Here is the link to my page and I posted the code here. Any help is appreciated.

http://scf.usc.edu/~diuguid/itp104/homepage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <title>Project Homepage</title>
</head>
<style>
#outercontainer{
    width:820px;
    height:1200px;
    background-color:orange;
}

#header{
        width: 300px;
        height: 60px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    color:red;
    font-size:40pt;
}

#drop-nav{
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
}

a{
    display: block;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }

 ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }

  ul li{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid blue;
    }

  li ul{
    display: none;
  }

  ul li a{
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
  }

  ul li a:hover{
    background: blue;
  }

  li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }

  li:hover li{
    float: none;
  }

  li:hover a{
    background: #f00;
  }

  li:hover li a:hover{
    background: #000;
  }

  #drop-nav li ul li{
    border-top: 0px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="outercontainer">
    <div id="header">
      LA SPORTS
    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="drop-nav">
    <li><a href="#">NBA</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="nba.html" target="_blank">Lakers</a></li>
      <li><a href="nba.html" target="_blank">Clippers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">MLB</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Angels</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dodgers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">NHL</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kings</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">NFL</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Past Teams</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what properties you want to change ?

Comment: If you look at the link of the page I've made and you hover over the menu options, you can see the problem. I want to make the drop down even with each menu option.

Answer (score 0):

Add this is your css:

```
ul li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: That did help! But the dropdown part still overlaps into the next menu option. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I am not getting you, how it overlaps.can you show ?

Answer (score -1):

Just go through this link

> http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css

this will be helpful to you for making dropdown.